# Content disappear when I turn Wordpress debug off

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I run to a issue with one of the Wordpress site I worked on.
I was having issue with event expresso plugin, so I turn web.config debug on tried to fix the issue, after I don't have any error warning on the homepage, **I turn off the web debug off, then the whole content is disappeared. I can't figure out why.**

Also tried this below, every time have "false" then the whole content won't display.(just a blank block, I check console, they did pull the information, but it's blank.)

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

Wordpress version: version: 4.9.8
Plugin use: Event expresso + wpbakery page builder

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to comment out the line `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`?

Comment: @JaredChu yes, if WP_debug is false or comment out, the content section will not display.

Answer (score 0):

I find out one of my code to remove empty

tag code in function.php is cause this issue, after deleting it, it's back to normal now.